# How to count value in rows cell table

Tags: javascript, html, function, html-table

If I have more than 1 rows where each rows have 3 column with the inputbox , maybe look like this:

```
<table id="mytable">
<tr>
    <td><input value = "1" /></td>
    <td><input value = "2" onBlur="goCount(this)" /></td>
    <td><input value = "2+1" /></td>
</tr>   

 <tr>
    <td><input value = "3" /></td>
    <td><input value = "4" onBlur="goCount(this)" /></td>
    <td><input value = "3+4" /></td>
</tr>
```

counting must be between cell 1 + cell 2 and the result will show in third cell, maybe the function must be like this :

```
function goCount(btn) {
var x = btn.value;
var y = ??? ;
var z = x + y;
}
```

but I do not know how to do that, First  get the cell 1 as value and  put the result on cell 3 but still in each same rows
is there someone who would help me to resolve this, thanks ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your solution

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tj4hn9e3/)

Your code should be like this

```
<table id="mytable">
<tr>
    <td><input value = "1" onBlur="goCount(this)"/></td>
    <td><input value = "2" onBlur="goCount(this)" /></td>
    <td><input value = "" id="result"/></td>
</tr>   

 <tr>
    <td><input value = "3" /></td>
    <td><input value = "4" onBlur="goCount(this)" /></td>
    <td><input value = "" /></td>
</tr> 
    <script type="text/javascript">
function goCount(btn) {
var x = btn.value;
//var y = ??? ;
        var res= document.getElementById("result") ; 
        //alert( res.value);
        if(res.value == "") {
            res.value = 0 ; 
        }
        res.value = parseInt(res.value) + parseInt(x) ;

}
</script>
```

***Note: Here is one thing you should note, I have used particular ID to return value in that, if you are using this for many rows you should use jQuery to navigate to that element in respective row and print result in it.***

Comment: a little confused in here... with Jquery mean i am count first how many rows in table, then if i have 1 specific rows selected, execute this code ... right ?

Comment: no no, you just get cursor is blurred from which button and then find his parent, then this parent's last <td> and then input,

Comment: if you don't wanna mess in jquery you can simply do that by JavaScript.